# How to delete "In code" views?

Tags: views

Some Drupal views I have are "In code" (while some others are "In database"); I understand that some are hard-coded in some PHP files and some are coded in the SQL.

Generally, what are the PHP files in which the "In code" views are stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name convention for default views provided by a module uses the extension **.views_default.inc**.

Alternatively, if a module isn't using standard naming conventions, you can search the code base for [`hook_views_default_views_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_default_views_alter/7) implementations (e.g. `grep -r '_views_default_views_alter' .` ) to find these views.